# To update UIProgressView for Multiple File Download (how to use delegate)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, download, singleton, delegates, uiprogressview

I am trying to update the multiple file download progress value to UIProgressView on a table cell.  I have the FileDownloader class which has NSOperationQueue that does asynchronous download operations.  I am thinking to update the UI using a "delegate" from FileDownloader class.  But I cannot compile the codes. I have FileDownloader as Singleton.  I am wondering whether I am missing to understand something fundamental.

The following is the setup of the code.

FileDownloader.h

```
#import < Foundation/Foundation.h >
// declare protocol to accept progress status of file downloads
@protocol FileDownloaderDelegate < NSObject >
// this function will update the progressview and re-display the cell
- (void) updateProgessWithCurrentValue:(NSNumber*)value totalValue:(NSNumber*)totalValue;
@end

@interface FileDownloader : NSObject {
 NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;  // for file download operations
 id < FileDownloaderDelegate > delegate;  // to send progess value to UI
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id < FileDownloaderDelegate > delegate;


+(FileDownloader*) sharedInstance;  // FileDownloader is Singleton with its standard methods

// when download is progressing, the delegate function will be called like
//  [self.delegate updateProgessWithCurrentValue:10 totalValue:100];
// 

@end
```

MyTableViewCell.h

```
 #import  < UIKit/UIKit.h >
#import < FileDownloader.h >
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell < FileDownloaderDelegate > {
 UIProgressView *progressView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIProgressView *progressView;

// MyTableViewCell.m will have the implementation of 
// - (void) updateProgessWithCurrentValue:(NSNumber*)value totalValue:(NSNumber*)totalValue;
// to update UI

@end
```

First, I got "**cannot find protocol declaration for FileDownloaderDelegate**" compiler error in MyTableViewCell.  So I moved out the protocol declaration of FileDownloaderDelegate to a separate .h file to be able to compile.  Even then, I still cannot assign to the delegate from my tableViewController using

> [[FileDownloader sharedInstance] setDelegate:myTableViewCell];

I got the "**FileDownloader may not respond to setDelegate method**" warning, meaning it does not know the delegate (although I have "@synthesize delegate").  I am wondering whether I am not understanding something about singleton or delegate usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your `+sharedInstance` method returns a `ContentSyncer*`, not a `FileDownloader*`.  That may be the cause of the `setDelegate: not found` warning.

Also, you can and should define your FileDownloaderDelegate protocol in FileDownloader.h.  Import this header file in MyTableViewCell.h, but use quotes instead of angel brackets.  E.g.,

```
#import "FileDownloader.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The ContentSyncer was a left-over when I renamed the classes to make the code easier to read for posting here. I reedited the code. The code is compiled after I separated out the protocol declaration to a separate file according to a suggestion from here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233371/how-to-conform-to-a-self-made-protocol
I read somewhere that there might be some "circular imports". But I don't know where that happen. Now I can get updates from the UI's tableCell. The only thing left is compiler warning when I assign the delegate. Thansk!